# How "\\p{javaUpperCase}.*\\." pattern really works?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string: 
"Perl is the only language that looks the same before and after RSA encryption." :)
This pattern `"\\p{javaUpperCase}.*\\."` looks for uppercase character and period. It returns true for that string, but if I remove word "Perl" it'll give me `false`. Why is that? There's still "RSA" word, which is uppercase too.

`\p{javaUpperCase}` - stands for UpperCase character
`.` means any character after that UpperCase
`*` is Greedy quantifiers, one or more times
`\\.` - period.

Where am I wrong? Why does it look only at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: what do you do with the pattern?

Comment: FYI, `*` means **zero** or more, not *one* or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because it is trying to match the whole string. (Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html says **"It is important to remember that String.matches() only returns true if the entire string can be matched"**). Depending on what regular expression library/function you use, it might require a match on everything.

Without "Perl", the string doesn't start with an uppercase character, so even though a substring matches, the whole string doesn't.

Try `.*(\p{javaUpperCase}.*\.).*` to match substrings.

The `.*` added on both ends allows extra characters on either end of the substring of interest.

Comment: If you are trying to do a substring match, it is probably better to use `Matcher.find(...)` rather than `Matcher.match(...)` ... especially in the case where the match might fail.